# Visual Basic sender not coming back as control

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, basic, sender

I have a windows application with 2 forms.

frmMain has a button (btnEditAgent) on it that opens frmEditAgent:

```
Public Sub btnEditAgent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditAgent.Click
    frmAgentEdit.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Then on frmEditAgent load:

```
Private Sub frmAgentEdit_Load(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    MsgBox(sender.Name, vbOKOnly, "verify")

End Sub
```

The sender comes back as "frmEditAgent" and not "btnEditAgent"

I do not understand why this is happening.  In order for the rest of my code to work I need to know which button opened frmEditAgent.  Why is sender referring to the same form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender of the `Load` event is the `Form` that was just loaded. The semantics of `sender` wouldn't make sense otherwise.

Think of it this way: the button *opens* the form, but the form does its own loading, and so calls its own `Load` event with itself as the sender.

If you want to know which button opened the form, then you can add an instance variable to your dialog form's class and then just set that variable in `btnEditAgent_Click`.

`frmAgentEdit` can then just use that instance variable to know which button caused it to be opened.

Comment: Ok, now I understand.  Thank you.  Now I have to figure out a new way to write this program.

Comment: That was my next plan.  Thank you again.

Comment: @Katp00p Well if this answers your question then it would be nice of you to mark it as the answer. :)

Comment: Sorry about that, a million things going on.